# iptables rule -d ! (not destination) is giving me errors

Tags: iptables

How do I use the [!] option for a destination IP?

I'm trying to redirect out-bound WAN DNS traffic to my sinkhole, but I can't get the --destination [!] option to work.

For example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -d ! 134.134.134.134 -j ACCEPT
```

returns:

```
Bad argument `134.134.134.134'
```

I haven't the slightest clue what is wrong with my syntax.

Answer (score 24):

You have the `!` in the wrong place. It belongs *before* `-d`.

From the `iptables` man page:

```
       [!] -d, --destination address[/mask][,...]
```

So for example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT ! -d 134.134.134.134 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That's right, it maybe should be added that this sort of notation worked with earlier versions. At least they took the command without error.

Comment: @John AFAIK the version of iptables that accepted the other syntax is so old that it's not included in any current Linux distribution for many years now.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This would explain a bit, I'm using a book from 2008 so it appears that was my issue, thanks! This drove me nuts. I did however learn about linux events so it's not all bad.

Answer (score 2):

try to put before --option

```
[root@pineapple ~]#  iptables -A OUTPUT -d! 134.134.134.134 -j ACCEPT
Using intrapositioned negation (`--option ! this`) is deprecated in favor of extrapositioned (`! --option this`).

[root@pineapple ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT ! -d 134.134.134.134 -j ACCEPT
[root@pineapple ~]# iptables -nvL | grep 134
78 92618 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !134.134.134.134
```